# Trouble adding Android Instant App capabilities: Failed to to resolve base-feature project module

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm trying to convert an existing app into an instant app and have been following the tutorials at: [Google codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#4)
and
[Building Android Instant App Tutorial - 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEfgSFk8-vw)

I am getting stuck at step 5 of the codelabs tutorial/ 10 minute mark in the youtube video where you have to put your base feature as a dependency of a new feature/apk module:

When I put "**implementation project(':blah-blah')**" I get the **error**: `Failed to resolve: Could not resolve project :blah-blah`.

I believe this is because :blah-blah is my root module so I think the child module might be having trouble accepting it as a dependency. I think this might be the problem because I also cannot rename :blah-blah for that reason as is recommended in both tutorials. I have also tried to explicitly declare :blah-blah in the settings.gradle file as was recommended online but to no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please provide some more context, such as the relevant parts of your build.gradle files.

Comment: @codySnyder, i hope it was mistake in understanding and it has been solved now https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#4, Please confirm.